# .Net Core Npgsql Prepared Statement

Tags: .net-core, centos7, npgsql

I've been trying to change some SQL statements in a .Net Core app to be more reusable by using Prepared Statements but I'm having trouble with the NpgsqlDbType.

I've tried to follow the documentations instructions.

```
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand (
    " select * from computers where com_phys = @com_phys ",
    dbconnection
);
command.Parameters.Add("com_phys", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);
command.Prepare();
```

But it is failing to compile, saying

```
The name 'NpgsqlDbType' does not exist in the current context
```

Am I missing something? How do I use the NpgsqlDbType?

*UPDATE*

I'm just putting the final working thing here in case it can benefit anyone else

```
// prepare

NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand (
    " select * from computers where com_phys = @com_phys ",
    dbconnection
);
var param01 = command.Parameters.Add("com_phys", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);
command.Prepare();

// execute 01

param01.Value = "value01";
var results = command.ExecuteReader();
while(results.Read()) {
   // nothing
}
command.Close();

// execute 02

param01.Value = "value02";
var results = command.ExecuteReader();
while(results.Read()) {
   // nothing
}
command.Close();
```

Comment: `NpgsqlDbType` is in the `NpgsqlTypes` namespace. Make sure you have a `using NpgsqlTypes` at the top, or use `NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar`

Comment: Amazing that worked thanks a bunch, feel very stupid now

Comment: I don't suppose you know how to set the parameter a value before executing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NpgsqlDbType is in the NpgsqlTypes namespace. Make sure you have a using NpgsqlTypes at the top.

If you want to set the value at the same time, use `AddWithValue` instead of `Add`

```cs
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand (
    " select * from computers where com_phys = @com_phys ",
    dbconnection
);
command.Parameters.AddValue("com_phys", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, value);
// OR command.Parameters.AddValue("com_phys", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, size, value);
// OR command.Parameters.AddValue("com_phys", value);
command.Prepare();
```

If you want to add the parameter once and execute multiple times, you can keep a reference to the parameter

```cs
var parameter = command.Parameters.Add("com_phys", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);

// Later, in a loop
parameter.Value = "someValue";
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. Is it not possible to Add without a value and set the value later for multiple uses?

Comment: @TheLovelySausage Updated the answer accordingly

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, the Npgsql Documentation was pretty confusing but this is perfect